# How to change audience of jwt using WSO2 API Manager

Tags: jwt, wso2-api-manager, wso2, audience

I'm using WSO2 API Manager version 3.0

I created one API in Publisher and with MyApplication subscribed it.

it gave me a JWt token. I Inserted JWt token on the https://JWT.io website.
The default value of `audience` in my JWT is `https://org.wso2.carbon/gateway`. How can I change the default `audience` value of my JWT token in the WSO2 API Manager?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the default Audience by logging into the WSO2 API Manager management console.

1. Log in to the management console (https://yourHost:9443/carbon)
2. Click on **Service Providers > List** from the left panel.
3. Select your application (`[user]_YOUR-APPLICATION-NAME_[PRODUCTION]`) and
   click on **Edit**.
4. In the **Service Providers** page, open **Inbound Authentication Configuration** > **OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration** and click on Edit.
5. In the **Application Settings** page, you can find the default Audience under the `Enable Audience Restriction` checkbox. You can add/ remove audiences for the application.

Once you have done the changes, click on Update to save the changes to the application.

Comment: What about other applications that the user generates? This would need manual changing, how can I change it programmatically for all applications?